# how to clear the cache in a yii query

Tags: caching, yii

I am utilizing Yii's sql caching to display data from a table (see below)

```
$results = Yii::app()->db->cache(1000)->createCommand($sql)->bindValues($params)->queryAll();
```

But the problem is, after I delete a value, this query still displays the values that have been deleted.  In my delete statement, how can I force the cache to be marked as dirty, so that the above statement doesn't display the old deleted data that is no longer there?

For your reference: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.data

Answer (score 1):

Instead of invalidating the cache during the delete, you can add a [dependency](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.data#cache-dependency) to the cache. If the dependency changes the cache is invalidated. e.g. if you are using an auto incrementing id, you can set the `max(id)` of the table to be the dependency:

```
$results = Yii::app()->db->cache(
        1000, 
        new CDbDependancy("SELECT max(id) FROM table")
    )->createCommand($sql)->bindValues($params)->queryAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cache query result in redis, you can open Yii debug mode and find the redis key, which is used in redis for your query result, then del the redis key.

Debug log follows:

```
2016/10/18 19:25:29 [trace] [system.caching.CRedisCache] Serving "Yii:dbquery:cc6401a98f142e12f880dc4ab9447813811d1saasase0e" from cache
2016/10/18 19:25:29 [trace] [system.db.CDbCommand] Query result found in cache
```